# Content DB Size Issue - How to Create New Content DB and Move

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, content-database

I'm very new to SharePoint 2010 Administration and have been asked to handle our Content DB Size issues. While not tremendously large right now we would like to handle the situation early.

I've performed several searches and have read many posts but I don't seem to be able to find a solution I need or understand.  Our Content DB is growing too large, from what I can tell I need to create a new Content DB and then move the site collection from the 'old' Content DB to the 'new' Content DB.

I'm looking for best practices, how to get this done, efficiently, doing this so my SharePoint site continues to work, and in a way that my headaches are kept to a minimum.

This SharePoint system and the Content DB is all still a little foggy to me right now.  In the future, after I understand this process, I'll probably be moving at least one site (contains tremendous amount of documents and added to on a daily basis) to it's own Content DB.

Thank you in advance for your help with this.

Answer (score 0):

I would follow this approach.

- Create a new content database and set the permission and Autogrowth for newly created Db.
- Now runt he [Move-SPsite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607915.aspx) command to move the site collection from
  current database to newly created DB. **Catch:** both DB should be
  on same SQL server and attach to same web application.
- Now Run IIS reset (this is requirement for Move-Spsite command).
- Due to IIS reset, i would schedule a time...Off peak hours or weekends.

Also I will try to clean up the site collection, delete the unused /un-required files from the site etc.

Comment: Thank you for the information. This is the disconnect for me, especially after your comment. If I'm moving the site to a new content db, doesn't this defeat the purpose of reducing the size of the db if all of the files are also being moved to the new Content db. Or is this just moving the site information, structures, pointers, etc., etc. and leaving files in the 'old' Content db. Sorry if the questions are redundant or very basic in nature right now.

Comment: when u move a site collection (not a subsite) then it will be moved alongwith everything (lists, libraries, subsites etc) to new db. it will free up space on ur exisitng db....lets say if you have 2 site collections in db and move site collection A (10Gb size) to new db then exisitng DB will be get 10GB free space...

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. I have at least one more question, probably a couple more.

If I run the following command, "Get-SPSite -Limit All | Get-SPWeb -Limit All | Select Title, WebTemplate, Configuration, URL" is it safe for me to say that each line item returned can be considered a 'Site' eligible to be moved to a new Content DB with the Move Site commands?